# Silverlight Binding Issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

Ok, So I have tried to implement a coverflow found on codeplex http://silverlightcoverflow.codeplex.com/

I wanted to use my own class for data binding:

```
    class CoverItem
    {
        BitmapImage _image;
        string _title;
        string _link;
        string _content;

        public BitmapImage Image
        {
            get { return _image; }
            set { _image = value; }
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }

        public string Link
        {
            get { return _link; }
            set { _link = value; }
        }

        public string Content
        {
            get { return _content; }
            set { _content = value; }
        }
    }
```

This is the XAML for the Cover User Control from codeplex:

```
<custom:CoverFlowControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="300" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Width="300" />
            <TextBlock Text="Testing" Width="300" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</custom:CoverFlowControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The problem I am having is that I get word "Testing" for each element that was bound, but I am not getting image or the title, which are from my objects that attached to the ItemSource property of the control.

```
Covers.ItemsSource = _items;
```

My question is, where am I going wrong? This should be a simple binding, so think I am missing something.

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT:

If I change the code to this:

```
List<BitmapImage> images = new List<BitmapImage>() { _items[0].Image, _items[1].Image, _items[2].Image, _items[3].Image };

Covers.ItemsSource = images;// _items;
```

And then have the binding as this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding}" Width="300" />
```

I now get my images displaying. So I know it is a problem with the binding somewhere.

Have also tried

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Width="300" />
```

Comment: What type of list is _items and when/how is it created? Also when are the individual CoverItems added to the list?

Comment: private List<CoverItem> _items = new List<CoverItem>();

Comment: They are populated from the contents of an xml file using an xmlreader, but that is not important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the `CoverItem` class public. One of the downsides of Silverlight is reflection permission on internal Types across assemblies is not allowed. When binding to CLR properties, reflection is used to get the value. The assembly that's trying to get the value is System.Windows, and it won't have permission to reflect an internal Type in your assembly.

I've written about this in context of anonymous Types (which are internal Types):
http://surrealization.com/blog/silverlight-anonymous-type-binding-gotcha/

Alternately you can provide an InternalsVisibleTo attribute on your assembly to allow System.Windows to "see" your internal Type.
http://grahammurray.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/binding-to-anonymous-types-in-silverlight/

For from-the-horse's-mouth description, see this MSDN link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc(VS.95).aspx

> In Silverlight, you cannot use
>   reflection to access private types and
>   members. If the access level of a type
>   or member would prevent you from
>   accessing it in statically compiled
>   code, you cannot access it dynamically
>   by using reflection.

And
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526229/in-silverlight-4-binding-to-an-internal-data-by-code-doesnt-work

> Silverlight supports binding to public
>   types only.

Comment: I love you!! Sorted my problem, can't believe I did not think of trying that!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked that CoverFlow project out yet, but from the way you define the bindings in your XAML, the `Image` property in your model is usually expected to be an `Uri` instead of an actual Image control:

```
    public Uri Image { get; set; } // should also be renamed to ImageUri
```

That's cleaner anyway. If you really, really must use an actual `Image` in your model, you'll have to define a `ContentPresenter` in your XAML.

As for why the `Title` would not display, I don't know.

Comment: This has the same effect, even using a Uri with the binding returns nothing. Like you I am confused why the text is not working. Binding in XAML has always confused me. :/